# Stop child processes after main program exits c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-process

After the completion of the parent's work, is the child still alive? If so, how can I kill him if the main process is complete? I used **boost** libraries **(boost process, boost asio)**. If it possible it should be a solution for **MacOs**, **Windows** and **Linux**.

```
boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
namespace bp = boost::process;
bp::child c(args);
ioservice.run();
c.wait();
result = c.exit_code();
```

Comment: Elaborate more on your intentions, which libraries you use, what is the meaning of the variables, and on which machine you intend to run the code. Answers depend on all of this.

Comment: @NadavS the library is in the tags

Comment: This is a boost process library, I intend to run in Linux, Windows and MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"after" it exits is probably challenging, but you could do it before it exits (or "as" it exits) easily.  Send each child an explicit message to shutdown via a pipe, for example.  Or, on most operating systems you could just send them a `TERM` signal.

You can register an `atexit` handler to do this but I would keep it simple and just put this feature on the program's natural exit point(s).

On the flip side, you could have children periodically check for their parent's status and exit if it's missing.

Comment: It's probably simplest if you tagged the question with an OS first.  OS-independent ways to do this are hard to come by.